# How to check if URL is reachable with angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, get, cross-domain

I want to check if a customer-provided URL actually contains data, so I don't have to take care of "broken" links. I created this directive so far:

```
app.directive('urlCheck', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('text', function(oldVal, newVal) {
                delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
                $http({
                    method: 'GET', 
                    url: newVal
                }).
                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("success")
                }).
                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log("fail")
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Basically, what it should do is on every change of text check if the text's URL is reachable and if not throw an "error". But I keep getting:

> ```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs51/f/2009/285/0/3/Binary_Code_Joke____Oh__jeez__by_SaiaraAuthorGirl.jp.
> ```
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

I found out that it has something to do with the browser blocking the actual request. Is there a way to get around this problem or is there an easier way to get the functionality that I need?

Comment: Google 'CORS' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers'. You need to set your API server to permit your requests.

Comment: Does it mean that both my server and server i send request to must have this feature enabled?